# Timeline doesn't work with 'some' durations

Tags: java, javafx

I have this working code:

```
Duration duration = Duration.millis(1000 / 30.0);
videoTick = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(duration, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("tick");
        }
    }));
videoTick.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
videoTick.playFromStart();
```

Perfectly. But once I change the duration slightly:

```
Duration duration = Duration.millis(1000 / 30.1);
```

It doesn't work anymore! Am I insane or JavaFx totally broken? How to work around it?

**Edit**: I know this bug looks not to make ANY sense, but it just happened in front of me. I provided the minimum code to reproduce it.

```
import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Ticker extends Application {
    private Timeline videoTick;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage) {
        Duration duration = Duration.millis(1000 / 30.0);
        videoTick = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(duration, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                System.out.println("Tick");
            }
        }));
        videoTick.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        videoTick.playFromStart();
    }
}
```

Then change the `30.0` to `30.1`.

**EDIT 2**:

<s>Ok, here is a (partial) workaround: `Timeline#play()` works when `Timeline#playFromStart()` doesn't.</s>(**EDIT 4**: sorry, this doesn't work. Obviously I'm too tired.)

But the problem isn't solved: what if you really need `playFromStart`? And more importantly, why it doesn't work with `1000/30.1`?

**EDIT 3**:

I reproduced it on OSX 10.8 + Java/JavaFx 1.7.0_17 and Java/JavaFx 1.7.0_21.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? Is an exception or error thrown?

Comment: In the former code Java prints "tick", "tick", "tick"... in the later one, nothing happens.

Comment: @jewelsea I'm using 7b17. Let me upgrade and test it.

Comment: I am able to reproduce this on Windows 7 with Java 7u15, but I'm unsure of the cause of the error.  The supposed `#play()` fix also does not work.

Comment: still doesn't work with Java/JavaFx 1.7.0_21, OSX 10.8.

Comment: Reproduced in JavaFx 1.7.0_21, OSX 10.8 using the 30.1 as the divider for the keyframe duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Java 7 Bug**

It's a bug with JavaFX in Java 7.  I created [RT-31027](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31027) in the JavaFX issue tracker to track this issue.

I was able to reproduce this (no tick output) using Java 1.7.0_21, OSX 10.8 when compiling and running from the command line.

Sorry for earlier mis-report that it was working in Java 1.7.0_21 (I had made a setup error with java version switching in my IDE).

**Fixed in Java 8**

It does work (ticks are output) in Java8b92, so the bug would appear to have been fixed in a later JavaFX build.  [Java 8 early access builds are available](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).  So as a workaround, you could use Java 8.

**Alternate Implementation**

For these kinds of animations, which happen very often, you could also consider using an [AnimationTimer](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/06/14/using-the-javafx-animationtimer/) instead.

**Update**

[RT-31027](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31027), the issue tracker record I created to track this, was closed as fixed in 8.0, with the comment "Only critical fixes are backported to 2.2, so closing this as fixed".

Comment: As much as I agree that it's most likely a bug, I'm weary of upvoting bug claims that don't have solid evidence that it is indeed, as claimed, a bug.  Referencing internal code or previous bug reports are sufficient to declare a bug's validity, in my opinion.

Comment: That's fine Vulcan, it doesn't need a vote.  There is no way to reference internal code on this as the relevant code is only open source for Java 8.  Many of the bug reports on the closed source code are not public, so could not be referenced.  I created [RT-31027](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31027) in the JavaFX issue tracker to track this issue.